# Spring SAML redirect URL after login which contains # character

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I am using Spring SAML for my application and I faced a problem with redirect URL after logged in successfully.
I am trying to save the URL before login to the app.
For example, When I access the link as http://localhost:8080/myapp/#request/123/details, spring-security will redirect to the login page.

I expected that after logged in successfully, the app auto redirect to the above URL. I have configured `sucessRedirectHandler` by using `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.
But, after logging in, the application redirects to https://localhost:8080/myapp/.

I also debugged and saw that the request URL does not contains "#request/123/details" part.
[image]

Do you have any ideas for this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting SAMLEntryPoint options, which preserves the requested URL as relay state.Check below code

```
@Bean
 public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
     SAMLEntryPoint entryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
     entryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
     return entryPoint;
 }
@Bean
 public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
     WebSSOProfileOptions options = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
     options .setBinding("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST");
     options.setRelayState(current-SP-URL);
     return options;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, I am trying to config as that way. But I am considering that how could we get a full URL as my example in the question above. Because the request does not contain the `#request/123/details` part as I said before. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I assume it is eating up everything after #. Is your UI a single page app with # being used as an anchor to jump to an element with the same name/id? Can you please try url-encoding # - > %23 ?